# Locating the Submit Button URL with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get to the URL behind the submit button:

[image: HTML]

```
 from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Safari(executable_path = '/usr/bin/safaridriver') 

#Fill in the required field
default_input = '111'
browser.get('https://trackapkg.com/aramex-tracking-number')
field = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ShipmentNumber"]')
field.send_keys(default_input)

url = browser.current_url 

#Click submit button to get the new URL
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='input-group-btn']").click();
while url == browser.current_url:
    time.sleep(5)
url = browser.current_url
print(url)
```

Submitting works (though inconsistently), but apparently there's an issue with Xpath to the button itself so it's not clicked and the URL can't be caught. I've tried multiple variants:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ShipmentNumber']/input[@class='btn btn-success']").click()
```

Or this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='btn btn-success']").click()
```

But still can find the solution. I will appreciate your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to be noted down.

1. Use `Explicit waits` for more **stability**.
2. Use relative xpath, prefer css over xpath. Also I see the `id` and 'Name' is **unique** so use `id` and 'Name' rather than `xpath`. Please see illustration below.
3. Launch browser in `full screen mode`.
4. When we click on `GO`, it opens a `new tab`, in Selenium we have to switch to new tab first before accessing anything in the new tab.

**Sample code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Safari(executable_path = '/usr/bin/safaridriver')

browser.maximize_window()
browser.implicitly_wait(50)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
driver.get("https://trackapkg.com/aramex-tracking-number")
default_input = '111'

field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ShipmentNumber")))
field.send_keys(default_input)


url = browser.current_url
print('current url', url)

#Click submit button to get the new URL
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "track"))).click()
time.sleep(5)

#When we click on GO, it opens a new tab, in Selenium we have to switch to new tab first before accessing anything in the new tab.

all_handles = browser.window_handles
browser.switch_to.window(all_handles[1])
new_url = browser.current_url
print('new url', new_url)
```

**Output :**

```
current url https://trackapkg.com/aramex-tracking-number
new url https://www.aramex.com/in/en/track/shipment-details?q=c2hpcG1lbnRJZD0xMTEmcHJvZHVjdEdyb3VwPUZSVCZzaGlwbWVudFR5cGU9Y2FyZ293aXNlJnNlYXJjaE1vZGU9YnlJZCY%3d-nc4VTy84z6w%3d
```

Comment: This works magic! And special thank you for noting a new tab, that could become my next issue

Answer (score 0):

The fault might be not waiting until the element is clickable. You could use

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

submit = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn btn-success']"))) 
submit.click()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. The error drops down right at the moment when the input is typed in with no waiting time at all

Answer (score 0):

If clicks on the button is intermittent on safari browser. Then here is one workaround. You can use enter key to click on the search box.

```
default_input = '111'
browser.get('https://trackapkg.com/aramex-tracking-number')
field = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ShipmentNumber"]')
field.send_keys(default_input)
field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

You need to import following library.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Therefore your code block would be like this

```
default_input = '111'
browser.get('https://trackapkg.com/aramex-tracking-number')
field = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ShipmentNumber"]')
field.send_keys(default_input)

url = browser.current_url 

field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)# press enter key for search

time.sleep(1) # wait for 1 second to check
while url == browser.current_url:
    time.sleep(5)
url = browser.current_url
print(url)
```